# Batch file to copy files based on file name to corresponding folder

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, copy

Trying to create a batch file that will copy files from one folder to another based on the description. For example if the file name has six digits I want it to read the first three digits and put it in a certain folder, if the file name has only five digits then I want it to read the first two digits and copy that file into a different folder.

File 704000.txt goes in folder T704

File 70400.txt goes in folder T70

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@echo on & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
goto start

the file structure should look simalar to this:

C:.
|   file.bat
|   
+---a
|       11111.txt
|       111111.txt
|       1111111.txt
|       22222.txt
|       222222.txt
|       33333.txt
|       333333.txt
|       44444.txt
|       444444.txt
|       55555.txt
|       555555.txt
|       66666.txt
|       666666.txt
|       77777.txt
|       777777.txt
|       88888.txt
|       888888.txt
|       99999.txt
|       999999.txt
|       
+---T11
+---T111
+---T22
+---T222
+---T33
+---T333
+---T44
+---T444
+---T55
+---T555
+---T66
+---T666
+---T77
+---T777
+---T88
+---T888
+---T99
\---T999

with this being file.bat

:start
set dir=a

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir %dir% /s /b') do (
   set filename=%%~ni
   set file=%%i
   if "!filename:~6!" EQU "" (if "!filename:~5!" NEQ "" ( move /Y "%%~i" "T!filename:~0,3!") else if "!filename:~4!" NEQ "" ( move /Y "%%~i" "T!filename:~0,2!"))
)
```